# GCloud MLEngine:Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Failed to load model: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Error code: 0)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to create version under google cloud ml models for the successfully trained tensorflow estimator model. I believe that I am providing the correct Uri(in google storage) which includes saved_model.pb.

Framework: Tensorflow,
Framework Version: 1.13.1,
Runtime Version: 1.13,
Python: 3.5

Here is the traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/ml_engine/versions/create.py", line 119, in Run
    python_version=args.python_version)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/versions_util.py", line 114, in Create
    message='Creating version (this might take a few minutes)...')
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/versions_util.py", line 75, in WaitForOpMaybe
    return operations_client.WaitForOperation(op, message=message).response
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/ml_engine/operations.py", line 114, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=5000)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 264, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms, _StatusUpdate)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 326, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 122, in IsDone
    raise OperationError(operation.error.message)
OperationError: Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Error code: 0)"
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Error code: 0)"
```

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

#### EDIT

I am using:
`tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', model.serving_input_fn)`
as a estimator exporter.

serving_input_fn:

```py
def serving_input_fn():
    inputs = {'string1': tf.placeholder(tf.int16, [None, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH]),
              'string2': tf.placeholder(tf.int16, [None, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH])}

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
```

PS: my model takes two inputs and returns one binary output.

Comment: Can you show us how you saved your model?

Comment: I have edited the questions post @DustinIngram 
```tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn=lambda: model.input_fn(
            test_data,
            test_labels,
            hparams.batch_size,
            mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL),
        steps=None,
        exporters=exporter,
        start_delay_secs=10,
        throttle_secs=10 ```

Comment: This generally means that when saved model was being restored, it failed to restore and the error message was the one you are getting. Are you able to restore locally?
You can email cloudml-feedback@google.com with your project# and model/version details and we can help debug further.